# Setting Advance Solver settings in Dymola

Tags: simulation, modelica, dymola

Is there a way to set the maximal solver stepsize (`hmax`) directly in Dymola?

The value for `hmax` can be changed in dsin.txt and it works if the simulation is run with dymosim.exe, but gets overwritten if simulation is started in Dymola.

Is there some hidden flag that I can use?

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem with the maximum number of event iterations `"eviter"` that gets overwritten after starting the simulation in dymola. I hope someone has figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

After editing `dsin.txt`, try to execute `dymosim.exe` directly instead of using the GUI (without parameters e.g. when executing via a double-click from the explorer this will create `dsres.mat` instead of `<modelName>.mat`). This should prevent Dymola from re-creating `dsim.txt` and therefore consider your setting for `hmax`.

Not very convenient, but currently the only way I know to make it work.

You can as well create `dsin.mat` and provide it as an argument for `dymosim.exe` to be able to re-create `dymosim.exe` using the GUI, without modifying `dsin.txt` every time. This is shown here: [dymola.readTrajectory - different sample times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55059721/dymola-readtrajectory-different-sample-times). You need to skip the second parameter `"<DymolaWD>\tgrid.mat"` obviously.

@Shanga: I think this should work for `eviter` as well, but I have no model to reliably test it. So feedback would be appreciated...

Comment: Also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36494628/maximum-number-of-event-iterations-in-modelica

Answer (score 0):

Setting maximum stepsize is only reasonable for solvers without stepsize control, e.g. Euler or Runge-Kutta. In those cases, a Fixed Integrator Step can be set in Simulation setup.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no convenient way to do this directly from Dymola.  The dsin.txt file has to be edited as you describe.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you set it through the parameters Interval length or Number of intervals in the General section of the Simulation Setup. The system will be solved at least on those points, which I understand as the maximum stepsize.

Comment: The solver step-size is not "limited" by the output interval (length or number) usually. E.g. if you simulate a simple model like `Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Examples.Accelerate`: For this model 1000 output points are computed. Still the solver log shows that (using DASSL) only 20 steps are computed - as it is simple to integrate. To check which steps the solver took, deactivate the "Equidistant time grid" flag in Dymola. 
Nevertheless the output interval can have an influence, as it is often taken into account when estimating the initial step size, which influences all following steps.