# dymola.readTrajectory - different sample times

Tags: python, dymola

Given a python script that triggers simulations in the Dynamic Modeling Laboratory (Dymola).

My goal is to get the data of the trajectories of my simulation, but in different sampling intervals. E.g. I want the transient section from 0 sec to 1000 sec to be sampled in 1sec intervals and the steady state section from 1000sec to 100000sec to be sampled in 100sec intervals **without having to perform two simulations with different start times, stop times and output intervals.**

An excerpt of the code that triggers the simulation for the **transient section**:

```
[result, simulation_result] = dymola.simulateExtendedModel(problem=problem,
                                                           initialNames=["input1", "input2", "input3"],
                                                           initialValues=[input1, input2, input3],
                                                           finalNames=output_names,
                                                           outputInterval=1,
                                                           startTime=0,
                                                           stopTime=1000,
                                                           resultFile=result_filename)

trajectory_size_transient = dymola.readTrajectorySize("simulation_result_python.mat")
sim_res_transient = np.array(dymola.readTrajectory("simulation_result_python.mat",
                                                                     output_names,
                                                                     trajectory_size_transient))
```

The code for the simulation of the **the steady state**:

```
[result, simulation_result] = dymola.simulateExtendedModel(problem=problem,
                                                           initialNames=["input1", "input2", "input3"],
                                                           initialValues=[input1, input2, input3],
                                                           finalNames=output_names,
                                                           outputInterval=100,
                                                           startTime=1000,
                                                           stopTime=10000,
                                                           resultFile=result_filename)

trajectory_size_steady = dymola.readTrajectorySize("simulation_result_python.mat")
sim_res_steady = np.array(dymola.readTrajectory("simulation_result_python.mat",
                                                                     output_names,
                                                                     trajectory_size_steady))
```

The value "outputInterval" is the interval in which the results are written into the trajectory. As seen, I have to perform two simulations and stack the results later on. I'd rather have one simulation with two different values of "outputInterval" and set

```
 startTime=0
 stopTime=10000
```

so that I can get two trajectories **from one simulation**.

Does anyone know if this is possible? Or maybe is there another approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following do what you need. It is a bit cumbersome, but should be worth the try:

1. Build a column vector containing the desired output points and store it in Dymola's working directory, e.g. using MATLAB:

```
tgrid = [0,10,13.75,97]'
save tgrid.mat tgrid -v4
```

2. Modify `dsin.txt` to look like this:

```
#    Method tuning parameters
double method(27,1)
       2                   # grid     type of communication time grid, defined by
                           #          = 1: equidistant points ("Increment/nInterval")
                           #          = 2: vector of grid points ("tgrid")
                           #          = 3: variable step integrator (automatically)
                           #          = 4: model (call of "increment" in Dymola, e.g.
                           #                      incr=Time > 2 then 0 else 0.1
                           #                      dummy=increment(incr))
                           #          grid = 1,3 is stopped by "StopTime"
                           #          grid = 2   is stopped by "tgrid(last)"
                           #          grid = 4   runs forever (stopped by model)
       1                   # nt       Use every NT time instant, if grid = 3
       3                   # dense    1/2/3 restart/step/interpolate GRID points
       0                   # evgrid   0/1 do not/save event points in comm. time grid
```

Usually the following has to be changed: 
(1) The flag in line 3 (`2`) activates the usage of the `tgrid`-vector.
(2) The flag in the last line (`0`) deactivates the creation of grid points at events.

3. Use `alist.exe` to apply the `tgrid`-vector to `dsin.txt` using the command line:

`"<DymolaInstallDir>\Mfiles\alist.exe" -b "<DymolaWD>\dsin.txt" "<DymolaWD>\tgrid.mat" "<DymolaWD>\dsin.mat"`

This should create a file `dsin.mat` in which the new grid is stored. This file should not be overwritten if the model is re-translated. Simulating from the Dymola GUI will ignore the settings in `dsin.mat`.

4. Simulate:

In `DymolaWD` execute `dymosim.exe -s dsin.mat`, which should result in the following for the given example:

```
Integration terminated successfully at T = 97
   CPU-time for integration      : 0.031 seconds
   CPU-time for one GRID interval: 10.3 milli-seconds
   Number of result points       : 4
   Number of GRID   points       : 4
   Number of (successful) steps  : 492
   Number of F-evaluations       : 19726
   Number of Jacobian-evaluations: 0
   Number of (model) time events : 0
   Number of (U) time events     : 0
   Number of state    events     : 0
   Number of step     events     : 0
   Minimum integration stepsize  : 0.000732
   Maximum integration stepsize  : 20
   Maximum integration order     : 7
Calling terminal section
... "dsfinal.txt" creating (final states)
```

and create a file `dsres.mat` containing the simulation's results.

Comment: Will give it a try and will let you know :)